# Can't delete file as root

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-mint, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption

Routine system update (Linux Mint 19) failed with an error about not being able to make a backup of a file. File has very weird owner and group and odd lsattr behavior. Can't delete the file as root.

```
$ ls -lah
total 64K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root       4.0K Sep 14 00:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root       root       4.0K Jul 20 06:18 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root        18K Jul 17 03:41 cs-xlet-danger.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root        13K Jul 17 03:41 cs-xlet-running.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root        19K Jul 17 03:41 cs-xlet-system.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 2558197760 2848915456    0 Jul 17 03:41 cs-xlet-update.svg
$ sudo rm -f cs-xlet-update.svg 
rm: cannot remove 'cs-xlet-update.svg': Operation not permitted
$ lsattr .
--------------e--- ./cs-xlet-danger.svg
--------------e--- ./cs-xlet-system.svg
lsattr: No data available While reading flags on ./cs-xlet-update.svg
--------------e--- ./cs-xlet-running.svg
```

I then boot into a live CD to check the file system.

```
$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sda1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda1: 291836/1310720 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 2935417/5242624 blocks
```

After the file system is confirmed good, I mount the drive and try to delete the file from the live CD OS (Linux Mint).

```
$ ls -lah
total 64K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root       4.0K Sep 14 04:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root       root       4.0K Jul 20 10:18 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root        18K Jul 17 07:41 cs-xlet-danger.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root        13K Jul 17 07:41 cs-xlet-running.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root        19K Jul 17 07:41 cs-xlet-system.svg
-rw-r--r--  1 2558197760 2848915456    0 Jul 17 07:41 cs-xlet-update.svg
$ sudo rm -f cs-xlet-update.svg 
rm: cannot remove 'cs-xlet-update.svg': Operation not permitted
$ lsattr .
--------------e--- ./cs-xlet-danger.svg
--------------e--- ./cs-xlet-system.svg
lsattr: No data available While reading flags on ./cs-xlet-update.svg
--------------e--- ./cs-xlet-running.svg
```

Finally I try deleting it by inode without success:

```
$ ls -i cs-xlet-update.svg 
220926 cs-xlet-update.svg
$ find . -inum 220926 -exec sudo rm -i {} \;
rm: remove regular empty file './cs-xlet-update.svg'? y
rm: cannot remove './cs-xlet-update.svg': Operation not permitted
```

How can I get rid of this file?

Comment: Didn't really (force) check the filesystem, without the -f flag e2fsck just took a quick look and said it wasn't marked dirty. And was it mounted writeable (rw)?

Comment: @Xen2050 Great idea! Unfortunately, that didn't find anything. I've edited my e2fsck line with the -f results. And yes the file system is mounted as rw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After forcing a fsck (with it's `-f` flag) and it still appears clean... The user/group numbers are unusual, generally they're under 10000 I think, two billion doesn't look right, and they're zero bytes... something's funny. Might be some extended attributes to check too, if these don't work.

Maybe try listing by inode

```
ls -il
```

and then delete by inode, with find and rm

```
find . -inum [inode-number] -exec rm -i {} \;
```

or another example recommended some find "safety" and find's -delete

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -inum [inode-number]  -delete
```

for even more "safety," first verify which file find has found by omitting the -delete, using the default "print"

```
find . -inum [inode-number]
```

---

If those still don't work, `debugfs` has some commands that should, and many of it's commands take an inode as an argument

```
   rm pathname
          Unlink pathname.  If this causes the inode pointed to by pathname to have
          no other references, deallocate the file.  This command functions as  the
          unlink() system call.
```

or maybe

```
   unlink pathname
          Remove the link specified by pathname to an inode.  Note  this  does  not
          adjust the inode reference counts.
```

---

And even if extended attributes are causing problems, you can try `getfacl` to list them & `setfacl` to change, the `-b, --remove-all` option sounds handy. Or in the `attr` package, there's also `getfattr` and `setfattr`.

Or debugfs has some extended attribute commands too like:

```
   ea_get [-f outfile] filespec attr_name
          Retrieve  the value of the extended attribute attr_name in the file file‐
          spec and write it either to stdout or to outfile.

   ea_list filespec
          List the extended attributes associated with the file filespec  to  stan‐
          dard output.

   ea_set [-f infile] filespec attr_name attr_value
          Set the value of the extended attribute attr_name in the file filespec to
          the string value attr_value or read it from infile.

   ea_rm filespec attr_names...
          Remove the extended attribute attr_name from the file filespec.
```

Comment: My original question showed that delete by inode was failing as well. However, it seems debugfs using rm pathname has worked. It gave no reason why it worked, or why rm wasn't working, but it appears I'm back in business. Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was just rm having problems, maybe find's `-delete` might've done something different. It did work out eventually, and others (in older posts, maybe when ext was less stable?) suggested that doing a fsck is a good idea after using debugfs